# Optimize a variable regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm matching the following strings:

- watermark=testing
- watermark=text-testing|position-24-50
- watermark=text-testing|position-24-50|color-6aa6cc
- watermark=text-testing|position-24-50|color-6aa6cc|size-48

using the following regex:

```
watermark=(text-\w+\|position-\d+-\d+\|color-([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})\|size-\d+|text-\w+\|position-\d+-\d+\|color-([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})|text-\w+\|position-\d+-\d+|\w+)
```

It works but it's so ugly it makes me want poke my eyes out with a hot stick. Would any of you regex gurus be willing to refactor it with a brief explanation on your methods?

Comment: It is probably better to split on `|` and then process each part separately.

Comment: Normally I would but it's imperative in this instance that the string is parsed as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
watermark=(text-\w+\|position-\d+-\d+(\|color-([0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}(\|size-\d+)?)?|\w+)
```

Since I observed (from example + original regex) that "size" implies all the fields in front are available, "color" implies all the fields in front are available, I just created nested optional:

```
(\|color-([0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}
  (\|size-\d+)?
)?
```

For `([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})`, I "simplified" to `([0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}`.

Comment: @JamesSouth: Fixed. Just swap `\w+` to the back.

Answer (score 1):

```
\bwatermark=(?:text-|)\w+(?:\|position-\d+-\d+(?:\|color-[0-9a-fA-F]+(?:\|size-\d+|)|)|)\b
```

Comment: Edited it slightly and came up with this which has slightly tighter color control.

`watermark=(?:text-|)testing(?:\|position-\d+-\d+(?:\|color-(([0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2})+(?:\|size-\d+|)|)|)`

Comment: Not sure if "testing" is a fixed string, since it's not specified as such in the original regex.

Comment: @JamesSouth - you should use `\b` as shown in my code, so you will not match strings like `mywatermark=...`

Answer (score 1):

You can run your regex through factoring software http://regexformat.com

Before:

```
watermark=(text-\w+\|position-\d+-\d+\|color-([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})?)\|size-\d+|text-\w+\|position-\d+-\d+\|color-([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})?)|text-\w+\|position-\d+-\d+|\w+)
```

After:

```
watermark=(?:text-\w+\|position-\d+-\d+(?:\|color-[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})?(?:\|size-\d+)?)?|\w+)
```

[image]

```
 watermark=
 (?:
    text- \w+ \| position- \d+ - \d+ 
    (?:
       \| color- [A-Fa-f0-9]{3} 
       (?: [A-Fa-f0-9]{3} )?
       (?: \| size- \d+ )?
    )?
  | \w+ 
 )
```

Comment: I'll have to check that website out. Functionality looks very useful. Thanks!